# php resize thumbnail to fixed dimensions - no crop

Tags: php, resize, thumbnails

I want to resize an image to a fixed size of 400x300.

I do not want to zoom crop it, I simply want the image constrained to either the width 400 or height 300 (depending on orientation), the image centered, and the rest of the image filled with black.

Does anyone know of a library/code that does this? (for GD)

Thanks,
Wesley

Comment: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/examples/resizing/

Answer (score 0):

[GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) can easily do this for you.

[Create a new image](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) with a [black background](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php) of the desired height, then [copy from the original, and place in the new](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php).

Perhaps another answer will come along with the full code, but this will get you started.  If not, I will post code for you later.

Comment: GD provides basic routines, but not something "higher-level" like what I asked above. I'll try some more..

Comment: @Wesley, I just added links to the three functions you need for this.